# Make scrollView page show text in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a scrollView that shows the first item in my Array, but I cannot get the second item to show when I scroll to the next page. Also, the text from first item in the Array shows when I am on the second page of the scrollView.

Could someone please help?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    var pageSize: Float = Float(scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    var page: Float = floorf((Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x) - (pageSize/2.0)) / pageSize) + 1
    //Bind Page limits
    if (page >= Float(numpages)){
        page = Float(numpages) - 1
    } else if (page < 0) {
        page = 0
    }
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)

    question.text = featureQuestions[pageControl.currentPage]

    println(pageControl.currentPage)
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    for var q = 0; q < numpages; q++
    {
        let mainFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(q), 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
        var question : UILabel = UILabel(frame: scrollView.frame)
        question.clipsToBounds = true
        scrollView.addSubview(question)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the frame for `question` to be `mainFrame` not `scrollView.frame`.

Comment: It didn't work. Same problem. Thank you for responding. http://imgur.com/jR1DEbX    Should I add multiple subviews? Because my array is inside of scrollViewDidScroll so the the label is updated when the user scrolls but is out side of view.

Comment: Ok, after fiddling with auto layout (not exactly sure how I fixed it) The label is successfully updating without moving out of view.